# How to obtain a list of sound cards on the system?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows

Exactly as the question sounds.

There is a list available at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses{6994AD04-93EF-11D0-A3CC-00A0C9223196} but it shows any USB based sound cards as `USB Audio` rather than `Plantronics Headset`.

Solution in either language listed in tags will do, but I can't use WMI, so that's out.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [MMDevice API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679147.aspx). Or [this .NET wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx) of such API.

The [`IMMDeviceEnumerator` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679033.aspx) is how you enumerate all of the available multimedia devices.

Comment: It looks like it's for Windows Vista or higher, unless I am misreading it.  I need something that will work on WinXP as well.

Comment: @AngryHacker: You're reading it correctly. The sound/multimedia APIs changed drastically from XP to Vista. There's no one-size-fits-all solution, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want a fallback solution for XP, you can enumerate audio devices using DirectX:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804969.aspx